# Registering multiple cron jobs in cron.yaml for AWS Worker Tier

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, yaml

I am having an issue registering more than one cron job to my AWS worker tier using the cron.yaml file. I added one cron job a couple months ago and everything works fine, but I cannot get additional jobs to register when I deploy to my worker tier.

When I run my deployment, I see the following event: `Successfully loaded 1 scheduled tasks from cron.yaml`. When I look over the access logs, I can see that the first job is making posts when it is scheduled to, but there is no record of the second job attempting to run. I verified that the new cron.yaml file is being checked into git. I also tested the route to make sure it was setup properly and ran into no issues.

I read [this AWS page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks) to add additional jobs to my cron.yaml file.

Any insight is much appreciated. Here is my cron.yaml file:

`version: 1
cron:
 - name: "scores"
   url: "/score/route"
   schedule: "0 0 * * *"
 - name: "drip"
   url: "/drip/route"
   schedule: "0 12 * * *"`

Comment: Hi there, am having the same issue, could you able to resolve it?.